# open another view responding to ajax request cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm sending ajax request to post some form data into cakephp controlller and then move the user to another page to upload some images. Here is what I did :

1- in the add.ctp view of feedbacks/add controller/action , i added the javascript code. I used jquery ajax and sent the form data

2- in the add action in the feedbacks controller I wrote this code :

```
public function add() {

        if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {

//commenting the next 3 lines has no effect
$this->layout = 'ajax'; // Or $this->RequestHandler->ajaxLayout, Only use for HTML
                $this->autoLayout = false;
                $this->autoRender = false;

            $response = array('success' => false);

            $data = $this->request->input(); // MY QUESTION IS WITH THIS LINE
           // var_dump($data);

            $this->render('/Uploads/add');
            // exit();
        } else {...}
```

Now I can see the response in firebug as html but the browser does not redirect.

Can any one tell me wt is the problem here ??

Thanks

Comment: logic is flawed. AJAX won't cause browser to redirect. You would have to use javascript to redirect based on response message from server

Answer (score 2):

Generally when you use this kind of form submits you want to work with JSON. That's the standard used implementation with jQuery we use.

Try to develop a good JSON response, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

In jQuery wait for the success to happen:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:baseUrl + '/Uploads/add',
    type:'POST',
    data: dataInModel,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('you got success!');
        console.log(data);
        //example reloading uploads:
        $('#uploads').load(baseUrl + '/Uploads/index');
    }
});
```

In your success function you do whatever you want. So for example you could put in a reload, redirect etc. But that's not really ajax. If you added an upload it would for example be ajax like if you would reload the list with uploads only. That's a raw example I added in the code example above.